# Scalafmt in Scala projects

Tags: scala, scalafmt

I like the clean code, I mean code formatted with for example scalafmt (https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/).

I've always add the file `.scalafmt.conf` in the root folder of the project. Then, everytime I save a source file it gets formatted accordingly.
As far as I know I can also add a plugin in the `plugins.sbt` file. With this, there are new sbt tasks for checking if sources are formatted, format sources, etc.

Q1 Is this the right way to use it (adding the `.scalafmt.conf` file and adding the plugin)?

Q2 Version in the plugin must be the same as version in `.scalafmt.conf`? Example:

`.scalafmt.conf`:

```
version = 2.6.4
...
```

`plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scalameta" % "sbt-scalafmt" % "2.4.3")
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That usage is correct.

The docs explicitly say that `scalafmt` and the sbt plugin are released independently.  The plugin version only covers the bits required to integrate `scalafmt` with sbt: it will download the version of `scalafmt` specified in `.scalafmt.conf` as needed.  In short, `scalafmt` and the sbt plugin will almost surely *not* have the same version number.